# Extract rows with a loop based on a condition R

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements, bioinformatics

I know this question has been asked a few times but I can't seem to make this work...

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                            Slycopersicum_O_F30 Slycopersicum_O_F31
BGI_novel_G000585            4.085328            3.886572
BGI_novel_G000600            4.085328            3.886572
BGI_novel_G001004            4.085328            3.886572
BGI_novel_G001146            4.085328            3.886572
BGI_novel_G001147            4.085328            3.886572
BGI_novel_G001673            4.085328            3.886572
```

With a total of 24 columns. Now I want to extract rows that meet my criteria which is that

The median of columns 1:21 should be greater than the median of columns 22:24. For this i wrote the following loop:

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(OpenTable)){
  if (median(as.numeric(OpenTable[i,1:21])) >
      median(as.numeric(OpenTable[i,22:24]))) {
    print(i) -> list 
    OpenTable[i,1:24] = SLU
}}
```

so the print function works just fine and prints all the lines that meet the criteria. However the last line of code only extracts 1 row (I guess they get changed out every loop)
Can anybody help me figure out how I can populate a dataframe with the rows that meet the criteria?
I hope I have stated this question correctly and please let me know if you require additional information.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with a loop. It should be easier to think about this in terms of vectorized functions. Here's how I'd do it (I'll edit the post if you share your whole data frame):

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(
   median(c_across(1:21)) > median(c_across(2:24))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you create an empty list:

```
my_list<-vector(mode = "list", length = (nrow(OpenTable))
```

Than use the for loop, but assign every selected row to your empty list:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(OpenTable)){
    if (median(as.numeric(OpenTable[i,1:21])) >
    median(as.numeric(OpenTable[i,22:24]))) {
    my_list[[i]]<-i
}
}
```

Your list will have NAs, which you should remove afterwards:

```
my_list<-my_list[which(!sapply(my_list, is.null))]
```